# Block form submit JS not working

Tags: javascript, forms, submit

I want to check some forms values before submit it. So I put this into my  :

```
<form name="frmcontact" id="frmcontact" method="post" action="<?php echo($action);?>" class="forms" onsubmit="return checkContactsFields()">
```

And here is my JS function :

```
function checkContactsFields(){
    var newIdValue = document.forms["frmcontact"]["new_id"].value;
    if(newIdValue !== 'ADRESSE NON IDENTIFIE'){
        var form = document.forms["frmcontact"].elements;
        for(var i = 0; i < form.length; i++) {
            if(form[i].name === 'street' || form[i].name === 'cp' || form[i].name === 'town'){
                if(form[i].value === ''){
                    console.log('ok');
                    document.getElementById('main_error_popup').style.display = 'table-cell';
                    if(form[i].name === 'street')
                        errorMsg = 'Voie';
                    else if(form[i].name === 'cp'){
                        errorMsg = 'Code Postal';
                    }else{
                        errorMsg = 'Ville'
                    }
                    document.getElementById('main_error_popup').innerHTML = 'Le champ ' + errorMsg + ' est vide';
                    return false;
                }
            }
        }
        return true;
    }
    return true;
}
```

The problem I have is that even with the return false statement, the form is submit..

Any idea of the reason ?

Thanks in advance

Comment: What value does the function return? Do you get any errors? Where is the related (minimal) HTML? Please see [*How to create a minimal, complete and verifiable example*](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 1):

Add `preventDefault` to the function & `submit` the form using ajax

In html

```
onsubmit="return checkContactsFields(event)"
```

in js

```
function checkContactsFields(e){
    e.preventDefault()
}
```

Comment: I try this, and I replace the "return false" by "e.preventDefault();" but the form is still submitted..

Answer (score 1):

A quick test in chrome seems to work if I 
just do :

```
function checkContactsFields(){
   alert("I won't submit");
   return false;
}
```

https://plnkr.co/edit/yA3hVlDtfUGxSCceqPMY?p=preview

If your javascript throws an error during execution the submit will still happen.

What does your html look like?

Comment: This isn't an answer, it should be a comment.